# Gnome 3 Desktop Environment: Window size and position hot keys?

Tags: gnome3, aero-snap, zorin

I'm looking to migrate to ZorinOS, which uses Gnome 3 Desktop Environment for window management.  I understand that the `super key` can be easily used as a modifier key and want to duplicate Windows 10 functionality in regards to super key hotkeys for window size and position.

The positions would be:

- maximize (win+up)
- minimize (win+down)
- minimize all (win+m)
- restore all (win+shift+m)
- resize to right half of screen (win+right)
- resize to left half of screen (win+left)

It would also be nice to have AeroSnap functionality, but this is a different but similar question.

Is this possible given the Gnome 3 Desktop Environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Aero Snap shortcuts are already present in a standard GNOME Shell environment. "Minimize" isn't really useful because GNOME Shell doesn't have a desktop.

That said, it still has the core functionality (e.g. "minimizing" a window hides it to the overview) and the shortcuts can be reassigned.